# How to access value of clickable link in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am converting a string into a link dynamically using link() function. This link would open a JavaScript function which needs the value of link to write further logic. JavaScript function is getting called successfully but not able to capture the value of link.

I have checked "this" and "document" to locate the value but cannot see it. Also not able to capture clickable event.

I have an array ReqArr with below structure showing rows 0 to 5. I am showing it as a grid on webpage.

```
0: {Request_No: "1001", Request_State: "Draft", Owner: "ABC1"}
1: {Request_No: "1002", Request_State: "Closed", Owner: "ABC2"}
3: {Request_No: "1003", Request_State: "In Progress", Owner: "ABC3"}
4: {Request_No: "1004", Request_State: "Closed", Owner: "ABC4"}
5: {Request_No: "1005", Request_State: "Draft", Owner: "ABC5"}
```

I want to show request numbers as clickable links so that I can click it to check request details. I am accessing array as shown below and using link() function to insert anchor tags and href pointing to JavaScript function.

`ReqArr[0].Request_No.link("javascript:openRequest()");`

Output of above code is:

```
<a href="javascript:openRequest()">1001</a>
```

Function openRequest is getting called successfully when Request number 1001  is clicked. In this function, I will be using request number 1001 to write a logic to open the request 1001. 
However, I am not able to get the value 1001 in function. Could you please suggest how can I find the value?

Comment: How `openRequest` looks?

Comment: Hi, I was trying to capture the value in openRequest function using parameter but did not work. This function will capture the value and use it for further logic.

Comment: It's not exactly answer my question but anyway, if you want to pass a parameter to a function you're doing this: `<a href="javascript:openRequest(1001)">1001</a>` and the function will be: `function openRequest(param) { console.log(param)}`

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you for suggestion. I have tried the option suggested by EvgeniiMalikov in below conversation but getting an error message.

Comment: What error message?

Comment: @MoshFeu Error was "Uncaught ReferenceError: RQ is not defined" Issue has been resolved now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy to hear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to click event instead of calling inline function.
In this case you link should like like

```
<a href="#" class="openRequest">1001</a>
```

And use something like this in your JS code:

```
$(function(){
 $('a.openRequest').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var requestId = $(this).text();
  console.log(requestId);
  alert(requestId);
 });
});
```

To get value of a tag inside you openLink function, where this refers to current element.

Or simply put `Request_No` to function argument and use this argument.

```
ReqArr[0].Request_No.link("javascript:openRequest('"+ReqArr[0].Request_No+"')");
```

Comment: `this` won't refer to the element using inline function shown

Comment: Yes, he should attach event listener instead of using inline function.

Comment: Edited my answer - now includes correct eventListener example

Comment: Hi Evgenii Malikov, thank you for the suggestion. The link() function takes only one parameter i.e. URL. Hence I am not able to assign any id or class.  
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Why you are forced to use link function? It's deprecated and better to create link using modern methods.

But if you can't use other functions, just pass a parameter inside.
`ReqArr[0].Request_No.link("javascript:openRequest("+ReqArr[0].Request_No+")");`

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov Request is a string in my actual data. For example RQ1001. Sorry I mentioned only numbers in my sample code. When I pass it as a parameter as you suggested, click on link shows an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: RQ is not defined". I think it is not able to recognize it as a parameter. Thank you for highlighting that link() is deprecated function. Other option I that could find was to append it as child to document but it did not work in my case. Could you please suggest any other methods to generate a link from string?

Comment: Could you provide source of your `openRequest` function?

Comment: I've edited my answer - argument now passed as a string - please not extra single quotes aroun argument

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov Adding extra single quote worked perfectly :) Thank you so much for your time and help.